Understanding the induced map on cubical homology groups.
I am studying from Massey's "Singular Homology Theory" book. On this book, the homology groups are defined from singular cubes. I will define some elements very quickly.
A $n$-singular cube on a topological space $X$ is defined as a continuous map $T: I^n \longrightarrow X$, where $I^n$ is the unit interval on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
From here, it is defined the free group generated by all the $n$-cubes, $Q_n(X)$. We take the quotient by the degenerated $n$-cubes (singular $n$-cubes that don't depend on a variable), and the group of $n$-chains is defined, $C_n(X)$.
There is a boundary homomorphism $\partial_n : C_n(X) \longrightarrow C_{n-1}(X)$.
We arrive to the $n$-th homology group of $X$, $H_n(X)$, as the quotient of the subgroup of $n$-cycles ($\ker \partial_n$) by the $n$-borders (Im $\partial_{n+1}$).
Given a continuous map $f: X \longrightarrow Y$, there is an homomorphism $f_\# : Q_n(X) \longrightarrow Q_n(Y)$ defined by $f_\#(T) = f \circ T$. By taking quotients, we arrive to a final homomorphism $f_* : H_n(X) \longrightarrow H_n(Y)$.
Some exercises of this book ask to describe the homomorphism $f_*$ under certain conditions on $X$ or $Y$, but I am unable to visualize or fully understand this homomorphism, so I don't know how to describe it.
I have tried to take a random element of $H_n(X)$ and see what $f_*$ is doing, but I am not seeing any conclusion.
Do you have some tips or some approach that could help me to understand them?
